# Developer signup - Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I have a mobile application where I use Instagram APIs as well; for Instagram [here](https://instagram.com/developer/register/) it asks my website url; since my application is not a website, can I pass url? Does it really matter?

Thanks

Comment: @RobertMoskal thats for redirect URL not "Your website"!

Answer (score 1):

This dosen't matter. It could be:

- You're personal website
- You're app package (example: `com.inxdev.myinstaapp`)
- Or you Google Play/iTunes app URL

Hope this help!